# Why is MySQL changing null to zero?

Tags: mysql, null

I'm completely new to databases and SQL.
I have a column marked `NOT NULL`.
When I forget to give a value to that column when doing an INSERT, it inserts a 0 value in that column.
Is there anything I can do to make it return an error instead of changing the `NULL` to 0?

Comment: Do you have a default on that column?

Comment: Is it an integer column? Are you not passing a value at all, or you *believe* the value is empty?

Comment: @Jason McCreary Yep, it's an int.  It's when I forget that column in the INSERT statement so no value gets passed to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to have a look at the `SQL_MODE` configuration. It allows you to define how strict MySQL handles such things. By default it is pretty lenient which is not what I usually want. It also depends on the data type, especially with Dates it is less than optimal by default.

I personally go for `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` usually.

See the MySQL manual (5.0) here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html

Comment: I did "SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';" and now it returns an error message whenever I forget a NOT NULL column.  Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for this:

- You have a default value defined for that column
- Your column is `INT NOT NULL` and casts `NULL` to `INT`, which results in `0`

The second situation seems to be the case here, obviously. If you want to get an error instead, you could change the `SQL_MODE` to be strict. An other possibility is to do the input validation in your progam rather than leaving it to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a DEFAULT value for that column