# MySQL: null becomes 0 in INSERT and SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, select, insert, null

I am trying to do an INSERT statement using SELECT query statement into a table with two columns (item_id that is not null and price that can be null). The item_id is not auto-increment and I would do a select query from another table. So an example would be:

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
SELECT ((SELECT id FROM myCatalogue where name="Item X"), "500");
```

By doing just the SELECT statement alone, if Item X does not exist in list, the query would return:

```
| SELECT id FROM myCatalogue where name="Item X" | 500 |
| NULL | 500 |
```

However, when the whole INSERT + SELECT statement, the following is inserted into 'myTable' instead:

```
| item_id | price |
| 0 | 500 |
```

I want MySQL to prompt me an error when item does not exist in 'myCatalogue', such as 'Cannot insert the value NULL in column item_id' so i can go back to 'myCatalogue' to verify if this item exists. However it automatically change the value from NULL to 0 and inserts successfully. Hence I would like to ask how do I need to modify the statement such that it does not change NULL to 0?

This is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable 
( 
    item_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    price float unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: show create table myTable?? I think your item_id has default value of 0.

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of MySQL. It thinks it knows better what you want than you. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346244/why-is-mysql-changing-null-to-zero

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name, this is a good suggestion, but i'm not allowed to touch any other tables, unless i can set STRICT_ALL_TABLES only on 'myTable'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm beginner, it will work in theory. For `mysql`.

```
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT ((SELECT IFNULL(id,0) as id FROM myCatalogue where name="Item X"), "500");
```

For `MsSql`

```
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT ((SELECT ISNULL(id,0) as id FROM myCatalogue where name="Item X"), "500");
```

Hope this help for you.

Comment: please remember that, if your id is primary key, that can crush on null value insert again.

Comment: I would want the NULL to purposely appear so i know that it is an error and it wouldn't add into the database, but the select query somehow just changes it to 0.

Comment: So, you want to change to 0 is result is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
SELECT id, "500"
FROM myCatalogue
WHERE name = "Item X"
```

Is easier to work with. You could confirm if insert was successful through [`last_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

You can try with:

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
SELECT id, "500"
FROM myCatalogue
WHERE name = "Item X"
UNION
SELECT NULL, "500"
```

Obviously, `id` needs to be `NULL` enabled and `default`, which can be difficult if it's `PRIMARY`. If you have `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` and wants an error instead, you can run like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
(   SELECT id, "500"
    FROM myCatalogue
    WHERE name = "Item X")
    UNION
(   SELECT item_id, "500"
    FROM myTable)
    LIMIT 1
```

Aslong as `id` is `PRIMARY`, it will error over the fact you're trying to insert existing `id` into the table.

Comment: Which one? I pretty much gave you 3 different ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, but only the 3rd one is applicable because I have to use item_id as PRIMARY key. i tried the 3rd code, and it still inserts the item_id as 0.

Comment: First one should work aswell since it shouldn't insert anything if row isn't found. Are you sure you don't have a row in `myCatalogue` that's actually `0`?